# Can you catch a JNI error in a 3rd party library before a hard crash?

Tags: android, error-handling, java-native-interface

We are working on an Android app.   We are using the Chilkat library to handle the email communication and it works well.   Although, there may be a "issue" involving some JNI communication.  From internet research and discussing with Chilkat, the problem may involve how EMOJI's are processed in messages.

Periodically, we get an error that hard crashes the app and it comes from the library call.  It is a single line call that sometimes crashes depending on something within the message itself.  Our call is...

```
 tmpstr=email.getHtmlBody();
```

The hard crash error we get is:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0

Again, doing some internet searches on this message... this apparently is a more common issue than anyone wants but still needs to be addressed.  Chilkat is working on a fix but in the meantime, we need to continue with the app.

What I am trying to figure out if there is a way that we can catch the error and prevent the app from crashing... maybe just flagging this message and continuing with the next message?

Seeing how I have never tried to catch an error from a 3rd party library, I am not sure where to go with this.

Any suggestions or examples that might help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something the authors of the library really need to fix, as what you can do without the source code is limited.  However, android will let your run a service of your own creating in its own process, and you could call into this problematic library only from code in that distinct process, so if it crashes the rest of your app will not automatically as well, and might be able to usefully recover.  The user may(?) still see a crash message though.

Comment: I would add that a fix is trivial for your lib vendor, but involves big risks if done to keep it "as is"

Comment: Agree with all... fortunately the vendor fixed the error.   Trying to catch it and handle it never worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on error, you can always try to "fix" it. Working with legacy code is always hard and all you can do here are some hacks.

You can do few things here:

1. try to catch signals
2. make sure your app doesn't exit your JVM

Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-015/ and here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-016/

Maybe you will find some solution based on these samples.